# Two JsFiddles, the exact same code, one works one doesn't. Does anyone know the problem?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle, imagemapster

[This One Works](http://jsfiddle.net/KSaunders123/xz2pgfuy/2/):

```
<img id="vegetables" src="https://i.ibb.co/GvdnjSD/map-popup-Recovered.png" usemap="#veg" >
<map id="veg_map" name="veg">
   <area shape="poly" alt="" data-key="ET" href="#" coords="745,621, 742,623, 739,626, 738,632, 738,632, 738,632, 737,633, 736,634, 736,635, 737,635, 739,634, 740,634, 741,634, 743,632, 744,631, 745,630, 746,632, 745,634, 741,636, 740,637, 741,638, 741,639, 741,640, 740,640, 738,638, 735,636, 734,636, 735,637, 736,638, 737,640, 736,641, 738,641,
        739,641, 738,644, 738,645, 735,649, 734,649, 732,649, 730,649, 729,648, 729,647, 731,647, 733,647, 734,647, 734,646, 735,645, 735,644, 735,644, 735,642, 732,641, 731,640, 730,640, 729,641, 728,645, 727,648, 727,655, 726,657, 725,658, 718,666, 716,668, 713,673, 713,674, 712,674, 709,677, 706,677, 704,677, 703,677, 701,678,
        702,682, 702,683, 702,683, 701,685, 702,688, 702,688, 702,688, 699,688, 698,688, 698,688, 700,686, 699,683, 697,683, 697,683, 696,685, 695,686, 694,686, 694,685, 694,684, 693,683, 693,683, 686,683, 681,685, 680,687, 678,687, 676,686, 676,686, 675,686, 674,686, 670,687, 670,687, 670,687, 667,691, 665,696, 664,696, 664,696,
        664,693, 663,692, 661,690, 659,689, 661,687, 662,686, 662,686, 661,684, 659,682, 658,681, 658,680, 658,675, 658,674, 657,675, 655,675, 654,671, 654,670, 652,668, 652,667, 651,666, 650,665, 650,663, 650,663, 650,663, 645,660, 641,657, 639,655, 638,654, 641,651, 643,649, 642,648, 641,648, 638,644, 639,642, 639,640, 639,637,
        640,636, 641,635, 641,635, 640,632, 641,631, 642,631, 643,629, 643,627, 640,626, 632,630, 631,630, 629,629, 626,628, 623,626, 623,626, 620,625, 619,622, 619,621, 618,620, 618,618, 618,614, 619,612, 618,610, 616,608, 614,603, 614,603, 613,601, 611,601, 608,604, 605,603, 600,601, 595,601, 594,598, 597,592, 604,583, 611,574,
        614,571, 597,527, 596,524, 593,518, 589,509, 584,497, 579,485, 574,472, 569,460, 564,451, 561,443, 560,441, 562,440, 565,439, 574,436, 587,432, 601,427, 613,424, 622,421, 625,420, 626,420, 627,419, 628,420, 628,421, 626,423, 624,425, 624,426, 623,427, 621,428, 620,433, 624,438, 629,440, 631,440, 633,440, 633,442, 635,445,
        637,445, 640,446, 643,447, 645,451, 645,451, 646,451, 650,453, 650,453, 650,453, 650,454, 651,454, 651,454, 655,449, 658,449, 659,451, 659,451, 660,452, 662,454, 660,458, 658,461, 659,462, 658,464, 660,467, 662,468, 664,467, 665,470, 667,472, 671,473, 671,475, 669,476, 668,477, 668,481, 668,484, 665,488, 665,490, 667,491,
        668,491, 669,494, 671,495, 671,498, 670,499, 670,502, 672,503, 674,505, 674,509, 676,509, 678,509, 680,510, 682,512, 682,512, 686,515, 687,516, 690,516, 691,519, 693,521, 695,521, 698,521, 699,521, 699,525, 699,529, 699,533, 699,536, 701,536, 701,536, 701,536, 701,538, 702,542, 703,543, 706,544, 706,546, 705,547, 704,550,
        704,552, 702,553, 700,556, 700,562, 699,566, 698,569, 700,573, 701,574, 703,574, 706,574, 708,574, 711,578, 712,578, 712,578, 713,579, 713,581, 711,584, 710,586, 711,588, 718,590, 720,590, 722,591, 723,591, 724,592, 723,592, 721,595, 720,597, 720,598, 720,599, 720,599, 724,604, 724,605, 725,606, 729,605, 729,605, 729,605,
        730,607, 730,610, 732,611, 734,611, 736,611, 738,611, 739,614, 739,616, 743,619, 745,620, 745,621, 745,621" >
        <area shape="poly" alt="" data-key="NY" coords="628,420, 628,420, 628,421, 626,423, 624,425, 624,426, 623,427, 621,428, 620,433, 624,438, 629,440, 631,440, 633,440, 633,442, 635,445, 637,445, 640,446, 643,447, 645,451, 645,451, 646,451, 650,453, 650,453, 650,453, 650,454, 651,454, 651,454, 655,449, 658,449, 659,451, 659,451, 660,452,
        662,454, 660,458, 658,461, 659,462, 658,464, 660,467, 662,468, 664,467, 665,470, 667,472, 671,473, 671,475, 669,476, 668,477, 668,481, 668,484, 665,488, 665,490, 667,491, 668,491, 669,494, 671,495, 671,498, 670,499, 670,502, 672,503, 673,504, 675,504, 677,503, 679,503, 681,505, 686,507, 688,506, 689,504, 691,504, 692,506,
        694,505, 696,504, 701,503, 706,501, 707,506, 708,511, 709,517, 707,518, 705,520, 712,525, 718,527, 721,526, 742,520, 774,510, 790,505, 796,503, 802,501, 801,495, 799,490, 804,489, 809,487, 805,466, 808,465, 813,463, 817,462, 818,463, 819,464, 831,461, 839,499, 847,496, 848,496, 847,491, 873,483, 875,493, 878,492, 880,491,
        882,494, 885,494, 889,497, 890,502, 892,504, 898,503, 907,501, 911,499, 911,496, 912,493, 920,490, 921,493, 927,491, 928,491, 928,493, 928,493, 928,494, 929,494, 932,492, 933,492, 934,492, 934,491, 911,416, 888,340, 888,340, 888,340, 887,340, 887,340, 886,340, 783,372, 679,404, 668,407, 633,417, 632,418, 631,418, 630,418,
        630,419, 629,419, 628,419, 628,420" href="www.google.com">
        <area shape="poly" alt="" data-key="YK" coords="721,595, 723,592, 724,592, 723,591, 722,591, 720,590, 718,590, 711,588, 710,586, 711,584, 713,581, 713,579, 712,578, 712,578, 711,578, 708,574, 706,574, 703,574, 701,574, 700,573, 698,569, 699,566, 700,562, 700,556, 702,553, 704,552, 704,550, 705,547, 706,546, 706,544, 703,543, 702,542,
        701,538, 701,536, 701,536, 701,536, 699,536, 699,533, 699,529, 699,525, 699,521, 698,521, 695,521, 693,521, 691,519, 690,516, 687,516, 686,515, 682,512, 682,512, 680,510, 678,509, 676,509, 674,509, 674,505, 673,504, 674,504, 677,503, 679,503, 681,505, 686,507, 688,506, 689,504, 691,504, 692,506, 694,505, 696,504, 701,503,
        706,501, 707,506, 708,511, 709,517, 707,518, 705,520, 712,525, 718,527, 721,526, 742,520, 774,510, 779,508, 779,512, 780,517, 783,519, 795,515, 802,536, 808,534, 810,540, 776,550, 773,539, 769,541, 759,544, 750,547, 744,549, 743,548, 741,549, 743,552, 743,555, 739,556, 735,559, 734,560, 731,561, 731,562, 732,564, 733,566,
        733,569, 732,571, 733,573, 734,574, 734,576, 735,577, 726,580, 729,593, 728,595, 722,595, 721,595" href="www.google.com">
        <area shape="poly" alt="" data-key="TO" coords="848,496, 848,496, 847,496, 839,499, 831,461, 819,464, 818,463, 817,462, 813,463, 808,465, 805,466, 809,487, 804,489, 799,490, 801,495, 802,501, 796,503, 790,505, 779,508, 779,508, 779,512, 780,517, 783,519, 795,515, 802,536, 808,534, 810,540, 776,550, 773,539, 769,541, 759,544, 750,547,
        744,549, 743,548, 741,549, 743,552, 743,555, 739,556, 735,559, 734,560, 731,561, 731,562, 732,564, 733,566, 733,569, 732,571, 733,573, 734,574, 734,576, 735,577, 726,580, 729,593, 728,595, 722,595, 721,595, 720,597, 720,598, 720,599, 720,599, 724,604, 724,605, 725,606, 729,605, 729,605, 729,605, 730,607, 730,610, 732,611,
        734,611, 736,611, 738,611, 739,614, 739,616, 743,619, 743,619, 744,619, 756,612, 766,612, 777,615, 785,620, 788,622, 796,623, 807,623, 813,621, 812,620, 813,618, 816,618, 817,618, 820,616, 821,617, 819,619, 819,620, 820,620, 821,620, 823,619, 825,618, 827,617, 827,615, 826,615, 826,613, 828,613, 830,612, 833,612, 835,611,
        836,611, 838,611, 841,611, 843,611, 845,610, 847,610, 848,609, 852,607, 857,604, 859,603, 859,603, 861,602, 863,601, 865,600, 868,598, 869,597, 871,596, 872,597, 872,599, 869,601, 869,602, 870,604, 872,608, 873,608, 876,606, 877,605, 879,603, 882,601, 885,599, 887,597, 887,597, 889,596, 891,594, 893,593, 895,591, 895,590,
        895,588, 895,587, 897,587, 898,587, 899,588, 900,588, 901,588, 903,587, 905,588, 914,585, 914,584, 915,583, 914,582, 914,581, 915,581, 916,581, 917,581, 917,581, 917,580, 917,579, 916,578, 915,578, 914,576, 914,576, 914,575, 914,574, 916,574, 917,575, 917,575, 917,576, 918,577, 918,578, 919,579, 920,581, 921,580, 924,581,
        925,582, 922,583, 921,584, 923,585, 925,583, 927,582, 927,581, 926,580, 927,577, 927,573, 929,571, 937,567, 949,563, 954,560, 954,558, 953,553, 951,546, 948,537, 947,532, 942,534, 940,528, 936,529, 929,531, 924,532, 924,534, 924,535, 918,538, 916,533, 891,540, 889,542, 884,543, 881,544, 879,541, 874,543, 867,544, 865,545,
        865,547, 864,548, 861,549, 859,548, 859,545, 859,537, 858,533, 856,532, 853,530, 850,527, 849,526, 847,525, 846,524, 850,522, 854,521, 848,498, 848,496, 848,496" href="www.google.com">
        <area shape="poly" alt="" data-key="EY" coords="848,496, 848,496, 848,498, 854,521, 850,522, 846,524, 847,525, 849,526, 850,527, 853,530, 856,532, 858,533, 859,537, 859,545, 859,548, 861,549, 864,548, 865,547, 865,545, 867,544, 874,543, 879,541, 881,544, 884,543, 889,542, 891,540, 916,533, 918,538, 924,535, 924,534, 924,532, 929,531,
        936,529, 940,528, 942,534, 947,532, 934,492, 934,491, 934,492, 933,492, 932,492, 929,494, 928,494, 928,493, 928,493, 928,491, 927,491, 921,493, 920,490, 912,493, 911,496, 911,499, 907,501, 898,503, 892,504, 890,502, 889,497, 885,494, 882,494, 880,491, 878,492, 875,493, 873,483, 847,491, 848,496, 848,496" href="www.google.com">
        <area shape="poly" alt="" data-key="SC" coords="888,340, 911,415, 934,491, 938,503, 942,517, 947,532, 950,543, 952,550, 953,553, 954,556, 954,560, 955,560, 957,558, 959,555, 962,551, 964,547, 966,545, 967,543, 975,533, 976,530, 980,525, 985,522, 989,519, 994,514, 997,512, 998,511, 1000,513, 1002,513, 1003,512, 1003,510, 1004,508, 1006,506,
        1006,506, 1008,508, 1010,509, 1011,508, 1011,506, 1013,505, 1014,504, 1013,502, 1014,500, 1014,497, 1015,494, 1017,489, 1019,485, 1027,475, 1028,475, 1028,473, 1028,473, 1029,472, 1037,463, 1040,462, 1041,461, 1044,458, 1047,454, 1048,453, 1049,451, 1050,450, 1054,446, 1056,444, 1057,444, 1058,443, 1059,442, 1060,441, 1062,440,
        1063,439, 1067,436, 1074,431, 1080,429, 1085,428, 1088,427, 1090,426, 1093,426, 1095,425, 1098,420, 1101,417, 1104,414, 1112,405, 1113,404, 1114,403, 1115,403, 1115,402, 1115,400, 1115,399, 1117,399, 1121,393, 1128,383, 1130,378, 1133,374, 1134,372, 1133,371, 1132,372, 1131,372, 1131,372, 1130,371, 1130,370, 1129,369, 1127,367,
        1126,367, 1126,366, 1126,365, 1125,364, 1124,363, 1123,363, 1122,362, 1120,362, 1119,361, 1118,361, 1117,360, 1116,361, 1114,361, 1113,361, 1114,360, 1115,359, 1116,358, 1115,356, 1115,354, 1115,352, 1113,351, 1111,351, 1111,351, 1107,349, 1106,349, 1105,348, 1103,348, 1102,347, 1101,345, 1101,344, 1099,344, 1097,342, 1096,342,
        1096,341, 1095,337, 1093,333, 1091,327, 1090,323, 1083,305, 1078,287, 1075,278, 1067,282, 1038,291, 1011,299, 984,308, 956,318, 930,326, 905,334, 888,340" href="www.google.com" >
</map>
```

[This One Doesn't](https://jsfiddle.net/KSaunders123/bx92f75w/33/)

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  
<script
  src="https://www.outsharked.com/scripts/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>
  


<img id="vegetables" src="https://i.ibb.co/GvdnjSD/map-popup-Recovered.png" usemap="#veg" >
<map id="veg_map" name="veg">
   <area shape="poly" alt="" data-key="ET" href="#" coords="745,621, 742,623, 739,626, 738,632, 738,632, 738,632, 737,633, 736,634, 736,635, 737,635, 739,634, 740,634, 741,634, 743,632, 744,631, 745,630, 746,632, 745,634, 741,636, 740,637, 741,638, 741,639, 741,640, 740,640, 738,638, 735,636, 734,636, 735,637, 736,638, 737,640, 736,641, 738,641,
        739,641, 738,644, 738,645, 735,649, 734,649, 732,649, 730,649, 729,648, 729,647, 731,647, 733,647, 734,647, 734,646, 735,645, 735,644, 735,644, 735,642, 732,641, 731,640, 730,640, 729,641, 728,645, 727,648, 727,655, 726,657, 725,658, 718,666, 716,668, 713,673, 713,674, 712,674, 709,677, 706,677, 704,677, 703,677, 701,678,
        702,682, 702,683, 702,683, 701,685, 702,688, 702,688, 702,688, 699,688, 698,688, 698,688, 700,686, 699,683, 697,683, 697,683, 696,685, 695,686, 694,686, 694,685, 694,684, 693,683, 693,683, 686,683, 681,685, 680,687, 678,687, 676,686, 676,686, 675,686, 674,686, 670,687, 670,687, 670,687, 667,691, 665,696, 664,696, 664,696,
        664,693, 663,692, 661,690, 659,689, 661,687, 662,686, 662,686, 661,684, 659,682, 658,681, 658,680, 658,675, 658,674, 657,675, 655,675, 654,671, 654,670, 652,668, 652,667, 651,666, 650,665, 650,663, 650,663, 650,663, 645,660, 641,657, 639,655, 638,654, 641,651, 643,649, 642,648, 641,648, 638,644, 639,642, 639,640, 639,637,
        640,636, 641,635, 641,635, 640,632, 641,631, 642,631, 643,629, 643,627, 640,626, 632,630, 631,630, 629,629, 626,628, 623,626, 623,626, 620,625, 619,622, 619,621, 618,620, 618,618, 618,614, 619,612, 618,610, 616,608, 614,603, 614,603, 613,601, 611,601, 608,604, 605,603, 600,601, 595,601, 594,598, 597,592, 604,583, 611,574,
        614,571, 597,527, 596,524, 593,518, 589,509, 584,497, 579,485, 574,472, 569,460, 564,451, 561,443, 560,441, 562,440, 565,439, 574,436, 587,432, 601,427, 613,424, 622,421, 625,420, 626,420, 627,419, 628,420, 628,421, 626,423, 624,425, 624,426, 623,427, 621,428, 620,433, 624,438, 629,440, 631,440, 633,440, 633,442, 635,445,
        637,445, 640,446, 643,447, 645,451, 645,451, 646,451, 650,453, 650,453, 650,453, 650,454, 651,454, 651,454, 655,449, 658,449, 659,451, 659,451, 660,452, 662,454, 660,458, 658,461, 659,462, 658,464, 660,467, 662,468, 664,467, 665,470, 667,472, 671,473, 671,475, 669,476, 668,477, 668,481, 668,484, 665,488, 665,490, 667,491,
        668,491, 669,494, 671,495, 671,498, 670,499, 670,502, 672,503, 674,505, 674,509, 676,509, 678,509, 680,510, 682,512, 682,512, 686,515, 687,516, 690,516, 691,519, 693,521, 695,521, 698,521, 699,521, 699,525, 699,529, 699,533, 699,536, 701,536, 701,536, 701,536, 701,538, 702,542, 703,543, 706,544, 706,546, 705,547, 704,550,
        704,552, 702,553, 700,556, 700,562, 699,566, 698,569, 700,573, 701,574, 703,574, 706,574, 708,574, 711,578, 712,578, 712,578, 713,579, 713,581, 711,584, 710,586, 711,588, 718,590, 720,590, 722,591, 723,591, 724,592, 723,592, 721,595, 720,597, 720,598, 720,599, 720,599, 724,604, 724,605, 725,606, 729,605, 729,605, 729,605,
        730,607, 730,610, 732,611, 734,611, 736,611, 738,611, 739,614, 739,616, 743,619, 745,620, 745,621, 745,621" >
        <area shape="poly" alt="" data-key="NY" coords="628,420, 628,420, 628,421, 626,423, 624,425, 624,426, 623,427, 621,428, 620,433, 624,438, 629,440, 631,440, 633,440, 633,442, 635,445, 637,445, 640,446, 643,447, 645,451, 645,451, 646,451, 650,453, 650,453, 650,453, 650,454, 651,454, 651,454, 655,449, 658,449, 659,451, 659,451, 660,452,
        662,454, 660,458, 658,461, 659,462, 658,464, 660,467, 662,468, 664,467, 665,470, 667,472, 671,473, 671,475, 669,476, 668,477, 668,481, 668,484, 665,488, 665,490, 667,491, 668,491, 669,494, 671,495, 671,498, 670,499, 670,502, 672,503, 673,504, 675,504, 677,503, 679,503, 681,505, 686,507, 688,506, 689,504, 691,504, 692,506,
        694,505, 696,504, 701,503, 706,501, 707,506, 708,511, 709,517, 707,518, 705,520, 712,525, 718,527, 721,526, 742,520, 774,510, 790,505, 796,503, 802,501, 801,495, 799,490, 804,489, 809,487, 805,466, 808,465, 813,463, 817,462, 818,463, 819,464, 831,461, 839,499, 847,496, 848,496, 847,491, 873,483, 875,493, 878,492, 880,491,
        882,494, 885,494, 889,497, 890,502, 892,504, 898,503, 907,501, 911,499, 911,496, 912,493, 920,490, 921,493, 927,491, 928,491, 928,493, 928,493, 928,494, 929,494, 932,492, 933,492, 934,492, 934,491, 911,416, 888,340, 888,340, 888,340, 887,340, 887,340, 886,340, 783,372, 679,404, 668,407, 633,417, 632,418, 631,418, 630,418,
        630,419, 629,419, 628,419, 628,420" href="www.google.com">
        <area shape="poly" alt="" data-key="YK" coords="721,595, 723,592, 724,592, 723,591, 722,591, 720,590, 718,590, 711,588, 710,586, 711,584, 713,581, 713,579, 712,578, 712,578, 711,578, 708,574, 706,574, 703,574, 701,574, 700,573, 698,569, 699,566, 700,562, 700,556, 702,553, 704,552, 704,550, 705,547, 706,546, 706,544, 703,543, 702,542,
        701,538, 701,536, 701,536, 701,536, 699,536, 699,533, 699,529, 699,525, 699,521, 698,521, 695,521, 693,521, 691,519, 690,516, 687,516, 686,515, 682,512, 682,512, 680,510, 678,509, 676,509, 674,509, 674,505, 673,504, 674,504, 677,503, 679,503, 681,505, 686,507, 688,506, 689,504, 691,504, 692,506, 694,505, 696,504, 701,503,
        706,501, 707,506, 708,511, 709,517, 707,518, 705,520, 712,525, 718,527, 721,526, 742,520, 774,510, 779,508, 779,512, 780,517, 783,519, 795,515, 802,536, 808,534, 810,540, 776,550, 773,539, 769,541, 759,544, 750,547, 744,549, 743,548, 741,549, 743,552, 743,555, 739,556, 735,559, 734,560, 731,561, 731,562, 732,564, 733,566,
        733,569, 732,571, 733,573, 734,574, 734,576, 735,577, 726,580, 729,593, 728,595, 722,595, 721,595" href="www.google.com">
        <area shape="poly" alt="" data-key="TO" coords="848,496, 848,496, 847,496, 839,499, 831,461, 819,464, 818,463, 817,462, 813,463, 808,465, 805,466, 809,487, 804,489, 799,490, 801,495, 802,501, 796,503, 790,505, 779,508, 779,508, 779,512, 780,517, 783,519, 795,515, 802,536, 808,534, 810,540, 776,550, 773,539, 769,541, 759,544, 750,547,
        744,549, 743,548, 741,549, 743,552, 743,555, 739,556, 735,559, 734,560, 731,561, 731,562, 732,564, 733,566, 733,569, 732,571, 733,573, 734,574, 734,576, 735,577, 726,580, 729,593, 728,595, 722,595, 721,595, 720,597, 720,598, 720,599, 720,599, 724,604, 724,605, 725,606, 729,605, 729,605, 729,605, 730,607, 730,610, 732,611,
        734,611, 736,611, 738,611, 739,614, 739,616, 743,619, 743,619, 744,619, 756,612, 766,612, 777,615, 785,620, 788,622, 796,623, 807,623, 813,621, 812,620, 813,618, 816,618, 817,618, 820,616, 821,617, 819,619, 819,620, 820,620, 821,620, 823,619, 825,618, 827,617, 827,615, 826,615, 826,613, 828,613, 830,612, 833,612, 835,611,
        836,611, 838,611, 841,611, 843,611, 845,610, 847,610, 848,609, 852,607, 857,604, 859,603, 859,603, 861,602, 863,601, 865,600, 868,598, 869,597, 871,596, 872,597, 872,599, 869,601, 869,602, 870,604, 872,608, 873,608, 876,606, 877,605, 879,603, 882,601, 885,599, 887,597, 887,597, 889,596, 891,594, 893,593, 895,591, 895,590,
        895,588, 895,587, 897,587, 898,587, 899,588, 900,588, 901,588, 903,587, 905,588, 914,585, 914,584, 915,583, 914,582, 914,581, 915,581, 916,581, 917,581, 917,581, 917,580, 917,579, 916,578, 915,578, 914,576, 914,576, 914,575, 914,574, 916,574, 917,575, 917,575, 917,576, 918,577, 918,578, 919,579, 920,581, 921,580, 924,581,
        925,582, 922,583, 921,584, 923,585, 925,583, 927,582, 927,581, 926,580, 927,577, 927,573, 929,571, 937,567, 949,563, 954,560, 954,558, 953,553, 951,546, 948,537, 947,532, 942,534, 940,528, 936,529, 929,531, 924,532, 924,534, 924,535, 918,538, 916,533, 891,540, 889,542, 884,543, 881,544, 879,541, 874,543, 867,544, 865,545,
        865,547, 864,548, 861,549, 859,548, 859,545, 859,537, 858,533, 856,532, 853,530, 850,527, 849,526, 847,525, 846,524, 850,522, 854,521, 848,498, 848,496, 848,496" href="www.google.com">
        <area shape="poly" alt="" data-key="EY" coords="848,496, 848,496, 848,498, 854,521, 850,522, 846,524, 847,525, 849,526, 850,527, 853,530, 856,532, 858,533, 859,537, 859,545, 859,548, 861,549, 864,548, 865,547, 865,545, 867,544, 874,543, 879,541, 881,544, 884,543, 889,542, 891,540, 916,533, 918,538, 924,535, 924,534, 924,532, 929,531,
        936,529, 940,528, 942,534, 947,532, 934,492, 934,491, 934,492, 933,492, 932,492, 929,494, 928,494, 928,493, 928,493, 928,491, 927,491, 921,493, 920,490, 912,493, 911,496, 911,499, 907,501, 898,503, 892,504, 890,502, 889,497, 885,494, 882,494, 880,491, 878,492, 875,493, 873,483, 847,491, 848,496, 848,496" href="www.google.com">
        <area shape="poly" alt="" data-key="SC" coords="888,340, 911,415, 934,491, 938,503, 942,517, 947,532, 950,543, 952,550, 953,553, 954,556, 954,560, 955,560, 957,558, 959,555, 962,551, 964,547, 966,545, 967,543, 975,533, 976,530, 980,525, 985,522, 989,519, 994,514, 997,512, 998,511, 1000,513, 1002,513, 1003,512, 1003,510, 1004,508, 1006,506,
        1006,506, 1008,508, 1010,509, 1011,508, 1011,506, 1013,505, 1014,504, 1013,502, 1014,500, 1014,497, 1015,494, 1017,489, 1019,485, 1027,475, 1028,475, 1028,473, 1028,473, 1029,472, 1037,463, 1040,462, 1041,461, 1044,458, 1047,454, 1048,453, 1049,451, 1050,450, 1054,446, 1056,444, 1057,444, 1058,443, 1059,442, 1060,441, 1062,440,
        1063,439, 1067,436, 1074,431, 1080,429, 1085,428, 1088,427, 1090,426, 1093,426, 1095,425, 1098,420, 1101,417, 1104,414, 1112,405, 1113,404, 1114,403, 1115,403, 1115,402, 1115,400, 1115,399, 1117,399, 1121,393, 1128,383, 1130,378, 1133,374, 1134,372, 1133,371, 1132,372, 1131,372, 1131,372, 1130,371, 1130,370, 1129,369, 1127,367,
        1126,367, 1126,366, 1126,365, 1125,364, 1124,363, 1123,363, 1122,362, 1120,362, 1119,361, 1118,361, 1117,360, 1116,361, 1114,361, 1113,361, 1114,360, 1115,359, 1116,358, 1115,356, 1115,354, 1115,352, 1113,351, 1111,351, 1111,351, 1107,349, 1106,349, 1105,348, 1103,348, 1102,347, 1101,345, 1101,344, 1099,344, 1097,342, 1096,342,
        1096,341, 1095,337, 1093,333, 1091,327, 1090,323, 1083,305, 1078,287, 1075,278, 1067,282, 1038,291, 1011,299, 984,308, 956,318, 930,326, 905,334, 888,340" href="www.google.com" >
</map>
```

I've been searching for so long. I was told that I wasn't importing jQuery in the one that doesn't work, but I am importing it. Side note though, It does sometimes seem to disappear after a week or something, I'll refresh and the jQuery library is gone. Other than that I know the importing is working because error $ is not recognized is there, and then its gone after importing.

```
<img id="vegetables" src="https://i.ibb.co/GvdnjSD/map-popup-Recovered.png" usemap="#veg" >
<map id="veg_map" name="veg">
   <area>
</map>
```

Imagemapster is not a function is what I'm getting now despite having 100% imported it.

Comment: Pay attention to "frameworks and extensions included" section

Answer (score 0):

The working fiddle is referencing: http://www.outsharked.com/scripts/jquery.imagemapster.js. (Link working)

The non-working fiddle is referencing:
https://www.outsharked.com/scripts/jquery.imagemapster.js (Link broken)

(http: vs https)

Comment: Hey did you try editing the jsfiddle and seeing whether your proposed answer was the reason why it wasnt working, cause I just did, and that's not it. Also did you downvote my question? Why did you do it if you did.

Comment: I did not. So this might just be an issue with jsfiddle not allowing you to call an `http` site. I'm seeing this console error `Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`. If you run it locally on your desktop you should see the program running without error if you use `http`.

Comment: Ah it is http locally : (. I even copied the whole js file and placed it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Console says you are using mixed content. It means that you refer to script that is loaded via http, but jsfiddle is loaded using https. You can fix it like this: move http://www.outsharked.com/scripts/jquery.imagemapster.js to some CDN which works with https, update the link in the fiddle.

You may ask why the old sample works but your one does not. Looks like jsfiddle automatically transforms all links to https for new scripts like your one, but http still works for the old code.

Comment: My console never said I'm using mixed content. The only line I see it "Uncaught TypeError: image.mapster is not a function". 

I have the same problem in the code on my computer in visual studio........ why does that not work..... It's exactly the same as the one in the jsFiddle?

Also, did you downvote my question. If so why

Comment: It does the same thing in my code on my own computer in visual studio..... Do you know why that is happening?

Comment: If I downvote I always comment with reason. Try my advice please, if it does not help, let's speak further?